# Find a cell expression in an array of an other file with an additional criteria and output a cell in the found row

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

it could be that the answer is quite easy, but I will explain my specific issue.

I have a list of research articles with their journal ISSN number. I want to assign every article a score (similar to impact factor). This score is in an other xlsx file and every year has its own sheet in the file (I thought that is easier than putting all 20000x14years journals in on sheet).

So I need a formular that includes the expression like this:

- Identify the year of the article,
- find the ISSN number of that article in the array of the years
  spreadsheet in the other file and
- output the journal score (which is in a cell of the same discovered
  row).

The xlsx with the search criteria

[image]

This picture shows you an example of the search criteria and the formula cell where I want the value 2.625 (see other pic).

the xlsx with the arrays that needs to be searched and the value that is needed
[image]

This is the other file with all journal scores and I searched for the ISSN (red) in sheet 2008 in the array (orange) and the value I need in the first file is 2.625.

I hope it was not to confusing? What do you suggest?
Thank you for your help ;)

Comment: The [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) can be used to reference an open external workbook but it cannot be used to reference a closed external workbook. There are some VBA and third party  alternatives if you absolutely **have to** reference a closed external workbook.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, I suggest you have one column per yer in your result table, in front of each ISSN. This would make you:

```
ISSN    score2008   score2009   score2010   …   …
x1      frml2008    frml2009    frml2010    …   
x2      frml2008    frml2009    frml2010    …   
x3      frml2008    frml2009    frml2010    …   
x4      frml2008    frml2009    frml2010    …   
x5      …            …           …          …   
..
```

Then you may use the very useful formula *VLOOKUP*:
Say input data is in the other book, named "Book1.xslx" (same directory).
In G2 of your example, Formula must be:

```
=VLOOKUP(F2;'[Book1.xlsx]2008'!$C:$D;2; FALSE)
```

- `F2` is the value you search.
- `'[Book1.xlsx]2008'!$C:$D` is the array where you look for your value.
- `2` is the index of the value you want to return from the table you search.
- `FALSE` means the match must be *exact*.